# C# DataGridView - Table is not populating

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to display data that I pull from text files within my program.cs  to a `DataGridView`, but the table remains blank when I run the code.

Another problem I have is that when the form opens it stops running through the code.

Basically what the code does is it downloads .zip files from an sftp server, unzips a text file, reads through the file adding each line to an array and splits a certain line into an array. I'm trying to get the variables from that array to appear on a `DataGridView` in my form.

Here is my code:

```
class Machine
{
    public string MacNum { get; set; }
    public string CashCount { get; set; }
    public string VendCount { get; set; }
}

static class Program 
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string zipTemp = (@"C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Project Dex\zipTemp\");

        string machineCashCount = ("");
        string hostIP = ("0.0.0.0");
        string userName = ("UN");
        string passWord = ("PW");
        string remotePath = (@"/home/dex/RESPONSE/PROCESSED");
        string localPath = (@"C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Project Dex\Temp\PROCESSED\");

        Application.Run(new Form1());
        DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
        IList<Machine> machines = new BindingList<Machine>();
        dataGridView.DataSource = machines;

        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
            HostName = hostIP,
            UserName = userName,
            Password = passWord,
            PortNumber = 22,
            SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 96:48:96:52:8c:e7:de:c6:e1:00:08:7e:db:ad:e4:06"
        };

        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            session.Open(sessionOptions);

            TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
            transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

            session.GetFiles(remotePath, @"C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Project Dex\Temp\").Check();
        }

        DirectoryInfo directorySelected = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Project Dex\Temp\PROCESSED\");
        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in directorySelected.GetFiles("*.zip"))
        {
            fileNames.Add(fileInfo.Name);
        }

        foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
        {
            string zipFilePath = localPath + fileName;

            using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zipFilePath))
            {
                var selection = (from e in zip1.Entries
                                 where (e.FileName).StartsWith("01e")
                                 select e);

                Directory.CreateDirectory(zipTemp);

                foreach (var e in selection)
                {
                    e.Extract(zipTemp, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                }
            }

            DirectoryInfo dexDirect = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\mark\Desktop\Project Dex\zipTemp\");
            List<string> dexName = new List<string>();

            foreach (FileInfo dexInfo in dexDirect.GetFiles("*.dex"))
            {
                dexName.Add(dexInfo.Name);
            }

            foreach (string dexNames in dexName)
            {
                string dexFilePath = zipTemp + dexNames;

                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dexFilePath);

                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    machineCashCount = Array.Find(lines,
                        element => element.StartsWith("VA1", StringComparison.Ordinal));
                }
                string[] MCC1 = machineCashCount.Split('*');
                string[] nm = dexNames.Split('.');

                int nam = int.Parse(nm[0], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

                // Console.WriteLine((nam + (":") + "Total cash count: ") + MCC1[1]);
                // Console.WriteLine((nam + (":") + "Number of paid vends: ") + MCC1[2]);

                Machine m = new Machine();

                m.MacNum = nm[0];
                m.CashCount = MCC1[1];
                m.VendCount = MCC1[2];
                machines.Add(m);
            }
        }

        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you just generating a new `Form1` there at the end?  Shouldn't you be _doing something with Form1's contents?_  The detail here isn't enough, I don't think.

Comment: The DataGrid you are creating in Main() has the scope of the method Main(). It may very well be populating dataGridView, but that isn't the DataGridView that form1 will be displaying. Show your code for form1

Comment: Ive explained a bit more what the code does and added my form1 code but I haven't really touched that part. Without Application.Run(new form1()) the form window doesn't open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Delete

```
 Application.Run(new Form1());
 DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
```

and

```
dataGridView.DataSource = machines;
```

2.At the end change

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

to

```
Application.Run(new Form1(machines));
```

3.Add constructor to Form1:

```
 public Form1(IList<Machine> machines)
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     dataGridView1.DataSource = machines;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What your program is basically doing is it runs the Form, downloads the zip file, processes the zip file and that's it.

You will need to do all this in the form's form_load event or a button click event instead of the Main().

1. remove the Application.Run(new form1) from the beginning of the code. Not required.
2. Move everything before the last Application.Run(new Form1) [Note this is with 'F' which is the correct one] to the a private function inside the form. Let's call it processFile()
3. Call this processFile() in the Form1_Load() event.
4. Assign m to the DataGridView's data property and call DataGridView.Bind() to bind the data to the datagrid control.

UPDATE:
Since you have a button and a Button_Click event, put the processFile() in the Button's click event. When the form is displayed, click the button to get the whole process running